# Woocommerce Reset Password Not Working

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I've just updated to the version 2.2.7 of Woocommerce (using WP 4.0) and I'm having trouble getting the password reset to work.

Using a test customer account, I use the 'Lost Password' link, and once I've entered my address I receive the e-mail.

Only problem is the link in the email just takes me to the login page and doesn't reset the password.

Anyone had this issue?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I discovered the issue -

I found it was because the files in **mytheme/woocommerce/emails** were out of date.

The Woocommerce system status said they were up to date but when I copied the template files from the latest upgrade of woocommerce to override mine, it fixed the issue (Github showed some edits as well which confirmed this).

Answer (score 8):

Without wasting my time I used this code in my function.php file to resolve this issue.

```
add_filter( 'lostpassword_url',  'wdm_lostpassword_url', 10, 0 );
function wdm_lostpassword_url() {
   return site_url('/wp-login.php?action=lostpassword');
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can also get into a reset password loop (clicking reset link in email takes you to the form asking you to enter your email/username again instead of showing password reset form) if your host is caching the http://example.com/my-account/lost-password/ page.  I resolved this with a client site on WPEngine by asking support to add this URL to the cache exclusions list and the problem immediately went away.

Edit: an even better explanation is here https://wordpress.org/support/topic/woocommerce-password-reset-issue-resolved/ -- Note where the support agent says “I did a Varnish exclusion for everything along the path of ^/my-account” .

Comment: This was my issue. GoCache (a Brazilian CloudFlare competitor) was caching the user account page.

Comment: For the love of god, WPengine should warn you about this when you intall a site.  Migrated to WPEngine recently and spent way too much time debugging the broken reset password flow.  THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

Happened to me today, turns out it was a conflict with a theme, and I had to use this url:

http://example.com/?login=example.com&action=lost_password

Instead of the woocommerce's default:

http://example.com/my-account/lost-password/

Was helped by this issue:

https://themeforest.net/item/clever-course-learning-management-system-theme/8645312/comments?page=22&filter=all#comment_10485207

This will obviously not help you, OP, as you solved your own issue, but I hope it might help someone else as I tumbled on this question through a google search :)

Answer (score 1):

Our password resets are coming across with improperly formed URL now.

https://mo.../my-account/lost-password/?key=IMrwE2FnskfDp9pBPpkn&id=316

Note the & if we swap this manually in the URL to and ampersand (&) then the form loads properly.

We are now digging through the commits in Github to see when this was broken.

Comment: Ok we found out for us it was that we send emails using SendGrid. You have to disable click tracking under Settings > Tracking. Apparently their sanitizer collides with woo's. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the function wc_get_endpoint_url(). You can fix it by following code. Just put it in your functions.php of your child-theme.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_endpoint_url', 'sh_fix_lost_password_endpoint', 9999, 4);
function sh_fix_lost_password_endpoint( $url, $endpoint, $value, $permalink ) {
    if ( $endpoint == get_option( 'woocommerce_myaccount_lost_password_endpoint' ) ) {
        return $url . $endpoint;
    } else { return $url; }
}
```