# Cannot display the page of resetting my password

Tags: wordpress, passwords, reset

Hello I got a template of wordpress on envato market and I created a website and I logged out from the website and I forgot my password and I tried to reset it but I couldn't display the page of resetting my password. What should I do? Please help me. I took a video Please take a look. https://www.youtube.com/embed/GDHKzwY870o

Answer (score 0):

check this out [Woocommerce Reset Password Not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26592043/woocommerce-reset-password-not-working)

If the url above doesn't fix your issue,

try:

- Toggle(deactivate/test reset password page/activate) each plugin.

- Identify which plugin caused the issue

- Look into the plugin.